# when i try to enter decimal numbers like 0.5 infields given it is instantly changing to .5 in oracle forms

Tags: oracle, oracleforms

[image]

If  I enter values as 0.5 the zero before . is getting removed and displayed as .5 this is happening when i move to other field. is there any settings need to be done plz help

Comment: Why do you care?  They are exactly the same.

Comment: yeah but sometimes it gets confused for user if it is .4 or 4

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Open item's Property Palette and set **Format mask** to desired value. For example:

[image]

Comment: THis is working but how to avoid .0 after a number eg: 3.0 or 4.0 -- can u plz send me the format

Comment: You either want to see a decimal (and you'll then see 3.5 as well as 3.0), or you don't want to see it. You can't have both options in the same item (i.e. 3.5 but 3, without .0).

Answer (score 0):

If you don't want the .0 when the value ends with .0, I suspect you should be able to change the item's format mask programmatically based on the value.  I haven't tested doing something like this but I believe it would work.  Depending on how you designed your and and the flow as you go through it, the awkward part may be deciding which triggers to use to set the mask then reset the mask.

SET_ITEM_PROPERTY ('TEXT_ITEM1', FORMAT_MASK, < desired mask >)

The above would not work if the item is part of a multi-record block.